# Hamiltonians and symplectic transformations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, dynamical-systems, symplectic-geometry, hamilton-equations

Let $H:\mathbb{R}^{2n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a Hamiltonian function, $\phi:\mathbb{R}^{2n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2n}$ be a symplectic transformation, that is $(D_x\phi(x)) J (D_x\phi(x))^T = J$ for $J=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & -I \\
I & 0 \\
\end{array}\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{2n\times 2n}$, $C\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 2n}$ be a linear transformation satisfying $CJC^T=0$ and $K :\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function.

**Question**: For what Hamiltonians function $H(x)$ do there exist a $\phi$, $C$ and $K$ satisfying
$$ H(\phi(x)) = K(C \phi(x))$$

**Example**: If the Hamiltonian is a function of $p$ only H(p), then $\phi = id$, $C = (I,0)$ and $K=H$ will satisfy the above. The same could be said about functions of $q$ only $H(q)$. This also holds for when you can write $H(x) = K_1(Cx)$ for $CJC^T=0$. I would like to know more general classes of Hamiltonians for which there does not exist such a $K_1$ satisfying $H(x) = K_1(Cx)$, but there does exist one after a symplectic change of variables $ H(\phi(x)) = K(C \phi(x))$. We do not need to know what $\phi$, $K$ or $C$ are, just need to know that they exist.

Some background on why we choose this condition for $C$ can be found [here](http://www.global-sci.org/v1/jcm/volumes/v16n2/pdf/162-97.pdf?code=xFfdAVPsAdfxcf7dx5Ylyw%3D%3D).

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what you're asking here. Since the symplectic transformation $\phi$ is invertible, we have that $H(\phi(x)) = K(C\phi(x))$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^{2n} \iff H(y) =K(Cy)$ for all $y\in\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. Hence the "general" case is equivalent to the original case. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @user17945 you're absolutely right. What I am really trying to understand is how they can go from equation (3.4) to (3.5) in [this paper](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/epdf/10.1137/22M1472206). Essentially, they "assume" that there exists a K for their H (where they use $C = (I,0)\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times 2n}$). 

But as you point out, i don't see how transforming the coordinates under $\phi$ makes this problem different. It feels too good to be true (i.e., impossible) to be able to transform a general Hamiltonian system into one with $n$ additional invariants.

Comment: I agree with your assessment that the result is not true in general. I believe it is true locally (i.e. in some open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$), but if it were true globally, it would amount to saying the Hamiltonian system is [Liouville integrable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%E2%80%93Arnold_theorem), which is not true in general. Their "sanity check" works since the one-dimensional harmonic oscillator is Liouville integrable (in fact, any 2-dimensional Hamiltonian system is - the Hamiltonian by itself is the sole conserved quantity).

Comment: I think that if we could show anything locally, that would be a good result tho! Indeed, being able to transform a non-integrable system, to a locally integrable one, would be of interest. But I'm not sure what it means to be "locally integrable" (... e.g., a system foliated by at least one integrable leaf?). 

I think for this application, it would be ok to have a system that is nearly integrable/shear. E.g., one whose solution is the forward Euler method to very good approximation. 

I appreciate your insights on this topic so far!

Comment: So maybe my question should be: is it possible to find a symplectic map to transform an arbitrary Hamiltonian to one that is "nearly" integrable on an open subset? ... or failing that, what set of Hamiltonians is it possible to do this

Comment: This is certainly possible, it just isn't very interesting. Darboux's theorem says that you can always find local "canonical" coordinates, in which the symplectic form looks like $\omega = \sum_{i=1}^n dq^i\wedge dp_i$ (and in which Hamilton's equations have the usual "canonical" form). So long as you're not at a critical point of the Hamiltonian $H$, you can always arrange for $q^1=H$, say (by doing a further symplectic transformation involving $q^1, p_1$ only). So then $H, q^2, \ldots, q^n$ are "local" invariants (in fact, so are $p_2, \ldots,  p_n$).

Comment: The point is, these can't necessarily be extended globally. You're essentially performing a local transformation so that $p_1$ parametrizes Hamilton trajectories, and the remaining coordinates are the initial values of such a trajectory along some $2n-1$-dimensional surface. This isn't really helpful for solving problems, however, since finding such coordinates is equivalent to fully solving for the dynamics.